# Does this JSON object contain a variable?

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'm working with an API ([DocumentCloud](http://www.documentcloud.org/help/api)) using jQuery/JSON. I'm trying to retrieve a specific page of text, which the API *almost* provides.

The returned JSON contains an object called `resources.page` which offers the following:

```
text: "http://www.documentcloud.org/documents/293026/pages/ohio-higher-education-capital-funding-p{page}.txt"
```

The confusing part is the end: `p{page}.txt`

Is it possible to specify a page in place of `{page}` and return the content? (If I use "5" instead of {page} and [put it into the browser](http://www.documentcloud.org/documents/293026/pages/ohio-higher-education-capital-funding-p5.txt), I see the text I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use string.replace

```
    var text = "http://www.documentcloud.org/documents/293026/pages/ohio-higher-education-capital-funding-p{page}.txt",
    urlString = '';

urlString = text.replace('{page}', '5');

$.ajax({
    url: urlString,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success : function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
​
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dy22q/

..fredrik

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. I tried something similar (split) but wasn't sure what to do with the URL afterwards. I tried $.get(url,function(data){//...}) but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Also, is there no way to manipulate it within the API? Just strange that they'd program it like that.

Comment: $.get only does a get call and you probably get a cross domain error. You need to do a ajax jsonp request. updated my answer.

Comment: Many thanks fredrik. This is my first StackOverflow question and it went rather well :)